# Can an Indian citizen with US visa enter Colombia, even when Colombian visa has been denied?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, colombia

I am an Indian citizen, have worked in Colombia and Brazil before. I applied for a Colombian Work permit visa, and got rejected for no apparent reason (as confirmed with the Embassy.) In the rejection email, it is said:

> Be aware that you will only be able to make a new visa application in six months’ time counted as of today

Now, I was suggested by a friend who has traveled to Colombia before that, in the case I hold a US tourist visa, I don’t need to have a Colombian visa to enter the country.

Will I be allowed to enter before the 6 month, in the above scenario?

Comment: Just from a logical standpoint it doesn’t make sense. A country denied you a visa, however you think it would be okay to enter the country on an exemption provided to people holding visas of a different country?

Comment: I understand that a work permit was denied, but in this case I want to meet my girlfriend who’s Colombian, so the purpose of the visit is tourism.

Comment: It is difficult to say what will happen at the passport control. Maybe they already have a record of your refusal and when the agent enters your passport number, a recent refusal will be flagged. In which case you can expect a lengthy landing interview with a possibility of denial of entry and deportation (a bigger black mark) or maybe you will get lucky and will pass through easily. 6 months is not a lot of time. Considering long term view of things it may be better to wait it out.

Comment: Meet to a nearby country. You may increases chances if you go in Colombia with a return ticket and a plan for a short stay: so clearly tourism and not for working (do no work!) as your visa application. But without a clear reason of visa refusal, we (and you) do not know if it was just for working regulation/reasons, or for other personal reasons.

Comment: @PD101 It seems strange they did not give a reason for the visa refusal. Did you have a confirmed contract of employment in Columbia?

Comment: @Traveller I contacted the embassy and they said all the paperwork was in order, just the ministry refused on their own, and haven't provided a reason for the same. I had a solid contract with the company, the company has now shifted the contract to a US branch as I work remotely for them now. Although they did say with the current situation in Venezuela they are rejecting work permits rampantly as 99% applications are coming from there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, under [Colombia's visa policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Colombia), you *may be allowed* visa-free entry, as an Indian national who holds a visa (or residence permit) issued by the United States or a Schengen Area country.

However, that *does not mean you will be*, especially after being notified that you must wait six months before making a new visa application. Appearance at Colombia's border is very likely to be considered a *new visa application*, regardless of purpose (work, visit, relationship).

Under the circumstances, it may be unwise to test this policy, especially when Colombia's immigrations record would show that you have intentions to work and live there.